# BSG Exodus: What happens with a damaged base star on launch raiders?

Tags: battlestar-galactica

We played the Exodus expansion with the Cylon fleet option for the first time last night.

We had a situation where there was a single basestar on the main board, and we'd damaged it with the "can't launch raiders" token.

Then, the crisis told us "Basestars launch raiders".

What happens?
a) Nothing
b) Raider appears on cyclon fleet board

Comment: Nothing happens, unless there's a second (undamaged) basestar - in which case that one would launch raiders.

Comment: As that answers the question - why not put it as an answer? :)  Also - why not?  The rules seem unclear as they suggest that when you don't place on the main board, you place on the cylon board.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing happens. The Exodus rule regarding raiders launching states:

> **Launch Raiders or Activate Cylon Basestars:** When either of these icons
>   is resolved, if there are no basestars on the main game board, place 1
>   basestar on the Cylon Fleet game board, according to the placement
>   rules below, and advance the Cylon pursuit marker one space on the
>   Pursuit track

Adding to the Cylon Fleet game board has an explicit condition which is not met in your example: *no basestars on the main game board*.